# objective c for mobile web development

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-website

Is it possible to develop a mobile web application using objective-c? I've already search the net and know that c++, c# and java could be used in web development. Is there any expert or programmer that have already experience coding a website using objective-c. If so how different it is compare to PHP Script language.

**update:** I'm trying to create a mobile web application for ios devices. like fb, youtube, twitter.

Comment: Nothing is impossible, but why would you ever do that?

Comment: The dream of Objective-C on the server died with distributed objects, leaving only `oneway` as a testament of its short life.

Comment: How different is it?  I would say *completely*

Comment: A valid option would be: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { exec("php", argv[1], NULL); }`

Comment: Objective-C is quite different to PHP. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: i'm trying to create a mobile web application in ios. It is more likely like a fb app in ios device. would it be possible to use a objective-c language??

Answer (score 1):

You could try **Frothkit**

It is a *Objective-C web application framework* that brings the power and simplicity of *Cocoa* development to the *web*.

While froth web apps are technically deployable on many different platforms using *Cocotron*, currently our focus has been on the *Amazon EC2 cloud*.

**Benefits of Froth**

- Uses the tools and language Mac and iPhone developers have come to know and love.
- Reuse existing objc/c code from desktop applications.
- Simple view templating support.
- Very fast and scalable.
- Affordable hosting on Amazon EC2 Cloud.
- Multiple builds and deployments using standard Xcode deployments.

**Simple Example**

```
@interface WAHelloController : WebActiveController {
}

// http://myexample.com/hello
- (id)helloAction:(WebRequest*)req;

// http://example.com/goodbye
- (id)goodbyeAction:(WebRequest*)req;

@end


@implementation WAHelloController

- (id)helloAction:(WebRequest*)req {
        return @"Hello World";
}

- (id)goodbyeAction:(WebRequest*)req {
        return @"Goodbye";
}

@end
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17663543/730807)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do but:

1. You can run a web site on [obj-c](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstepWeb) (as opposed to, say, Cake PHP or Ruby on Rails), which could run a social network accessible from all kinds of browsers, and offering REST APIs and all that jazz. If you're super hot on Obj-C but not much else, I suppose this might be a good idea.
2. You can run a web server [on an iOS device](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer), I guess if you want a site on your wifi network.
3. You can run a web server, using whatever framework and server you like, that makes web sites that can be [added to the homescreen](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneWebApp/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008134), kind of like native apps. I *think* this is what you are actually asking about. This wouldn't need to use objective-c at all.

Answer (score 0):

From your update you are implying you ae trying to create an application for iOS that primarily accesses a website?

Then of course you can use Objective-C

If you want to make a web page and wrap it into an application you should look into PhoneGap - that being said I'm not sure if you can publish phone gap applications to the app store currently.

PhoenGap will wrap a mobile website into an iOS container.

objectice c is fine of the client but if you really want to write something maintainable for the server I would stay away from Obj-c and use something more common.